# I want to create web services with laravel

Tags: php, web-services, laravel, laravel-4

I want to create web services with laravel but i don't do this.

I use routes some one like this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'basic.outh'), function(){

    Route::resource('url',      'UrlController@index');
    Route::resource('show',     'UrlController@show');
    Route::resource('destroy',  'UrlController@destroy');

});
```

But this Route filter just want to username, like this:

```
Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic("username");
});
```

I want to be make my system like Codeigniter RESTful api. This is possible?

Could you suggest me any examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, definitely possible.

Personally, i would recommend using OAuth2 for token based authentication, which is better suited for APIs.  OAuth has a fairly steep learning curve, but luckily, there is a package for Laravel (an OAuth2 wrapper) that makes it pretty easy, as it will generate and validate the tokens for you.

**Package:**
https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

**Example:**
I have a setup similar to this.  The code below isn't meant to replace going through the documentation, but this is something like what your routes would look like using this wrapper.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'apiErrors'], function()
{

    // Returns a valid token based on grant_type and credentials when a request is made to the accessToken endpoint. 
    // I use 'client_credentials' and 'refresh_token' for APIs serving mobile apps, for example.  You can use that, or roll your own.
    Route::post('accessToken', function()
    {

        return AuthorizationServer::performAccessTokenFlow();

    });

    // 'oauth' filter makes sure there is a valid token present
    Route::group(['before' => 'oauth'], function()
    {
        // Your protected endpoints
        Route::resource('url',      'UrlController@index');
        Route::resource('show',     'UrlController@show');
        Route::resource('destroy',  'UrlController@destroy');

    });

});
```

Comment: @c-griffin can we use both token csrf token and oauth2. CSRF token for web form and Oauth2 token for api

Comment: Via the oAuth spec, the token is passed in the header.  If you're using https, the header will be encrypted.  But in short, there is nothing stopping anyone from using oAuth and CSRF in conjunction with each other.